# Is it OK to show localized pricing information in an ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I've read in a number of places (ie. http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/app-store/rejections) that you should not include price information in your app for either the "full version" or in app purchases.

The reasoning is generally that the apps are sold globally, and prices and currency vary by region.

I've used the localized currency value (I'm actually using MKStoreKit, it's great and you should try it), and I'm wondering if anyone has displayed localized price information in their app and had it pass app store submission?

I'd sure like to include the price in my promotional view for my IAP, but I don't want to be rejected for doing so.

Comment: Hey can you share the code how to get local price in MKStoreKit please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had no problems with apps that display the pricing information provided it's getting fetched on the fly from `MKStoreKit`. It's as much to do with local variations as global ones - Apple's restriction is designed to prevent situations arising where you might hard-code a pricing value into your app which subsequently goes out of date due to currency variations. For example, a month or so ago Apple re-calculated the pricing tiers for the Euro, Pound, and a few other currencies.

The best place to go for this information would be the Apple published guidelines, which have much improved: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: cool thanks,  I just wanted to make sure apple didn't can me for having prices in there.  Appreciate the approval guidelines link :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the official `Store Kit Framework` is the recommended way of doing it. It is advised that you don't display prices outside of this value as it can be confusing to customers. Through iTunesConnect, you can adjust prices remotely so there is never an un-localized, or conflicting price. In fact, I think you could even be rejected for higher priced items if you *don't* tell the user how much an in-app purchase is.

Comment: I think that the **recommended** way of doing this - is fetching the information from iTunesConnect server and not storing/hard-coding prices inside the application. Whether you use `MKStoreKit`, `Store Kit Framework` or anything else for in-app purchasing - doesn't matter.

Comment: You are right… I meant to type Store Kit, not MKStoreKit. editing.

Comment: The edit someone made to my question title was a poor one.  My question was not whether using MKStoreKit is appropriate.  It obviously is as it's just a wrapper over the StoreKit Framework.  I've rolled back that edit.  I was really just looking for someone's experiences with including pricing information in the app.  Thanks for your response